# Segmentation Faults Keep Appearing

Tags: c++, string, parsing, pointers, fault

Below I have a FileParser program that goes through an assembly language source code file, line by line, and divides the line into tokens ( label, opcode, operand, comment).

It keeps track of the label pointer until it reaches the end of the label, at which the label pointer value is passed to the next tokens start pointer ( opcode_start) which goes along the opcode until it hits the end, and then passes the pointer value to operand_start and so on. Think of it as passing the addresses down.

```
labelstart = x;
copies label value into string var; labelstart++
labelend = labelstart;
skips whitespace
opcodestart = labelend;
copies opcdoe value into str var , opcodestart++ ;
opcodeend = opcodestart
```

I have been debugging Segmentation Faults that have been occuring MAINLY at the points where I am copying char's at a pointer into a string, and passing off the pointer variables to the next one/

```
_label[i] = label_start[i];
_opcode[x] = opcode_ptr[x];
```

etc...

My last debugging run ended with a Segmentation Fault at the line 210

```
_operand[q] = operand_start[q];
```

What can I do correctly to ensure that both the addresses

```
void file_parser::read_file() {

ifstream wholefile;
string line;
int row_num = 1; // starting on first row
vector<string> rowlist; // data structure containing rows
int has_label = 0;  //booleans
int has_opcode = 0; 
int has_operand = 0;
int has_comment = 0;
char* label_start;  //marks startpoint of token
char* label_end;    // marks endpoint
char* opcode_start; // likewise\/\/\/
char* opcode_end;
char* operand_start;
char* operand_end;
char* comment_start;

// file_parser fileparse = new file_parser; //I don't think we actually need   this.

struct row tokens[BUFFER]; // array of row objects, with label, opcode, operand, comment fields
row *tokens_ptr = &tokens[0]; // for when we want to delete


wholefile.open(filename.c_str()); // opens file
//open_file();

int c = 0; // keeps track of current char
int result;
while( (wholefile.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit) != 0 ) {
    has_label, has_opcode, has_operand, has_comment = 0; // reset flags
//  tokens[row_num] = new row(); // create new row object in tokens array

    //////// deciding on wether to use vector<rowlist> or array of rows??????

    getline(wholefile, line); // takes line out of file and saves to 'line'

    if(line[c] == '*') {
        while(line[c] == '*'){
        getline(wholefile,line);
        row_num++;
        }
    }

//////////////////IF LINE STARTS WITH LABEL/////////////////////
    if(isalpha(line[c]) || isdigit(line[c])) // if first char on line is alpha or num
    {
        string _label; // its a label
        int i;

        for(i = 0; line[i] != ':'; i++)  // label goes up until ' : '
        {   if(i == 0) 
            {   label_start = &line[0];     // pointer to first char of label
            }
                                // loop quits once label ends (reaches colon)
            if(i == 8)           // if 8 characters have been put in
            {  _label[i] = '\0';
                label_end = &label_start[i]; 
            }
            _label[i] = label_start[i];  // copy the string as a token
        }

        if( i < 8 )
            _label[i] = '\0';
        label_end = &label_start[i];

        has_label = 1; // mark line as having label
        tokens[row_num].label = _label;
        tokens[row_num].has_label = 1;
    }

///////////////OPCODE//////////////////////
////IF LINE STARTS WITH OPCODE/////
if(has_label == 0) // if first char on line isnt letter or number
{
    tokens[row_num].has_label = 0;
    tokens[row_num].label = "";
    int i=0; // first token on this line is opcode
    while(line[i] == ' '){
        i++;
    }

    opcode_start = &line[i]; // ptr to first char of opcode token

    string _opcode;
    string opcode_ptr;
    int x;

    for(x = 0; opcode_ptr[x] != ' '; x++) // stops at whitespace, should clear leading blanks later
    {
        _opcode[x] = opcode_ptr[x]; // copy text into string
    }
    _opcode[++x] = '\0'; // null terminate opcode string

    tokens[row_num].opcode = _opcode; // set row properties
    tokens[row_num].has_opcode = 1;
    has_opcode = 1; // local variable
}
//////////OPCODE CASE 2///////////////////
////IF LINE STARTS WITH LABEL////
else if(has_label == 1)  // if line has label, pointer currently at end of label (on ':' char), get it to opcode//
{    label_end++; // move ptr to whitespace
    string _opcode;
    while(*label_end == ' ') {
        label_end++;
    }
    ////when loop exits, ptr has reached next column for processing////
    if(isalnum(*label_end)) // **COULD POSSIBLY DELETE || or even use isalnum?
    {
        int i; // if its a number or char//
        opcode_start = label_end; // we've reached the opcode area///

        for(i = 0; opcode_start[i] != ' '; i++) {
            _opcode[i] = opcode_start[i];
        }

        opcode_end = &opcode_start[i]; // opcode_end is on leading blank
        _opcode[++i] = '\0'; // null terminate string value

        tokens[row_num].opcode = _opcode;
        tokens[row_num].has_opcode = 1;
        has_opcode = 1;
    }
    ////////////OPERANDS/////////////////
} // LINE = LABEL---OPCODE---OPERAND

if(has_label == 1 && has_opcode == 1) // begin saving operand
{
    int i = 0;
    string _operand;
    while(opcode_end[i] == ' ') {
        i++;
    }                               // reached operands after loop

    if( isalpha(opcode_end[i]) || isdigit(opcode_end[i]) )
    {       
            operand_start = &opcode_end[i]; // save location
         }                           ////now that we've reached operand, decide if quoted or not
    //////// if QUOTED OPERAND/////////
    if((*operand_start = '\''))      // if it is
    {
        int x = 0;
        operand_start++; // move the ptr to the first char
        while(operand_start[x] != '\'') {
            _operand[x] = operand_start[x]; // and keep copying // them until ' is reached'
            x++;
        }

        // until the next quote is reached
        _operand[++x] = '\0';
        operand_end = &operand_start[x]; // operand_end on space
        // after ' char
        tokens[row_num].operand = _operand;
        tokens[row_num].has_operand = 1;
        has_operand = 1;
     } else 
     {      int x = 0;
        while(operand_start[x] != ' ') {
            _operand[x] = operand_start[x];
            x++;
        }
        _operand[x] = '\0';
        operand_end = &operand_start[x]; // operand_end on space // after operand
        tokens[row_num].operand = _operand;
        tokens[row_num].has_operand = 1;
        has_operand = 1;
     }    
    ////////////if an operand after a first opcode//////////
    /// LINE =  xxxxx  OPCODE   OPERAND
} else if(has_label == 0 && has_opcode == 1) {
    int q = 0;
    string _operand;
    while(operand_start[q] != ' ' || operand_start[q] != ';' || operand_start[q] != '*') {
        _operand[q] = operand_start[q]; // keeps copying until it reaches space or beginning of comment
        q++;
    }

    if(operand_start[q] == ';' || operand_start[q] == '*') {
        comment_start = operand_start; // mark location of comment beginning
    }
     else{  
    _operand[q] = '\0';
    operand_end = &operand_start[q];
    tokens[row_num].operand = _operand;
    tokens[row_num].has_operand = 1;
    has_operand = 1;  
    }
} /////////OPERAN

/////////////////check for comments///////////////
if(has_label == 1 && has_opcode == 1 && has_operand == 1) {
    int x = 0;
    string _comment;
    while(operand_end[x] != '\n' || operand_end[x] != ';' || operand_end[x] != '*') {
        x++;    // keep going until you reach a comment beginning or the next line
    }
    if(operand_end[x] == ';' || operand_end[x] == '*') {    //if theres a comment
        comment_start = &operand_end[x];            // mark its start point
        while(comment_start[x] != '\n') {   // and copy it in, until the line ends
            _comment[x] = comment_start[x];
            x++;
        }   
        _comment[x] = '\0'; //null term once youve copied it completly
        tokens[row_num].comment = _comment; // set the object data value
        tokens[row_num].has_comment = 1; // and the objects boolean
        has_comment = 1;        // and the local variable
    } else { // otherwise there is no comment, youve reached the end of the line
        if(*operand_end == '\n') {
            _comment = "";  // no comment value
            tokens[row_num].comment = _comment; //set object vals accordingly
            tokens[row_num].has_comment = 0;
            has_comment = 0;
            break;
        }   
    }       //if the line started with no opcode, follow the same algorithm as above...
} else if(has_label == 0 && has_opcode == 1 && has_operand == 1) { 
        int x = 0;
        string _comment;
        while(operand_end[x] != '\n' || operand_end[x] != ';' || operand_end[x] != '*') {
            x++;
        }
        if(operand_end[x] == ';' || operand_end[x] == '*') {
            comment_start = &operand_end[x];
            while(comment_start[x] != '\n') {
                _comment[x] = comment_start[x];
                x++;
            }
            _comment[x] = '\0';
            tokens[row_num].comment = _comment;
            tokens[row_num].has_comment = 1;
            has_comment = 1;
        } else {
            if(*operand_end == '\n') {
                _comment = "";
                tokens[row_num].comment = _comment;
                tokens[row_num].has_comment = 0;
                has_comment = 0;
                break;
            }       
        }       
}

//  c++;    probably dont need to increment this every line...
    row_num++;      // but definitley increment this 
    rowlist.push_back(line); // and pushes 'line' to back of vector
}
//  int i;
//  for ( i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
//  {   delete tokens_ptr[i];   //Once EOF has been reached, go through     //every
//  }                   // element of array and delete them 
    delete[] tokens; // before finally deleting the array as a whole
       //deallocation of memory helps ensure no memory  management issues at      runtime
};
```

Comment: if you don't know where exactly the problem in a huge code use the debugger if you know where post only lines where problem is

Comment: The current problem is at Line 210, as I stated. The entire code is posted for anyone to highlight where flawed coding/pointer practices that may be leading to the SegFault are taking place

Comment: while(operand_start[q] != ' ' || operand_start[q] != ';' || operand_start[q] != '*')    blabla , q can grow too much , you must also test q to do not be > operand_start length , bla bla

Comment: @user3390986 *The entire code is posted for anyone to highlight where flawed coding/pointer practices that may be leading to the SegFault are taking place*  -- C++ does not work this way.  A pointer issue can appear *anywhere* in your entire program, and only you see the final results of the pointer mismanagement later on.  Either post a [mcve], or reduce your entire usage of pointers to a bare minimum by using things such as `std::array`, `std::vector`, algorithms and iterators, etc.

Comment: In addition, you are asking a lot if you want someone to just eyeball two screensfull worth of code without actually running the code and come up with the answer.  There is a point where you can't just run the program "through your head" -- it needs debugging.

Comment: "to highlight where flawed coding/pointer practices" - consider **all** of your code highlighted! Without going into too much depth, here are simple ones: results of `std::getline()` are used without checking the success of the operation; indices into a string are used without checking how many characters there are; read `char` values are used with `<cctype>` functions witout making sure they are positive.